# I have made vow to Lord Shiva if i get particular college i will shave my head but now everybody's suggesting me that it will look bad in colllege?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

Instead of shaving my head and showing my devotion to the lord shiva what I can offer to the lord? Because shaving my head will not benefit anyone but instead of shaving can I give some donation?

Comment: why not shave if said, it also does no harm

Comment: Seriously brother what did you even think before offering something that holds no value to the supreme Lord Shiva??Whats with doing this business with the All-prevading omnipresent, omnipotent, omniscient God? Doing buisness with him that too in terms of material objects that hold no value is an insult to him, when instead he can give something much better than such petty boons if you pray to him sincerely.He has the power to liberate you(grant you moksha) and give you the highest bliss in this world, right now he must be laughing at your poor antics of pleasing him.

Comment: if you really want to offer something to the lord, dedicate your entire life to Lord Shiva.Do his bhakti(best way to please lord shiva in Kali Yuga), do his puja with utmost sincerity and devotion, dedicate your every action to please Lord Shiva, do charity and bestow compassion on all living beings, Lord Shiva's grace would always be showered upon you.Stop doing such business minded antics instead devote your entire being in his devotion.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22231/how-to-please-lord-shiva-to-get-grace
See this one too.I hope i may have helped even just a little bit!

Comment: If you made a vow you should fulfill it without fail. Not fulfilling any vow is not good specially if it's made to God. Looking bad is an extremely trivial issue and hair does not take much time to grow either.