# What are the right rituals & food for Maha Shivaratri fast?

Tags: shiva, rituals, worship, food, fasting

I would like to know the following:

1. The right type of food for the fast, so what to eat & when to eat?
2. The rituals to be performed before & after the fast?
3. Any precautions to be taken?
4. Any other additional information if you have related to this fast.

Agni Puran:

> The chaturdashi in krishnapaksha that comes between the months of
>   Magha and Falguna is known as Shivaratri. Then one has to fast and
>   **stay awake the whole night**. Earlier, there used to be an evil hunter
>   named Sundarasena. But because he performed a vrata on Shivaratri, all
>   his sins were forgiven.

In above reference by whole night does it means after the sunset till 12.00 midnight or after 12.00 midnight till sunrise?

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/rituals-to-be-performed-during-shiv-ratri-and-their-significance

Comment: @YDS it doesn't answer the qn fully.